# Pandas merge columns with the same name

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Dataframe:

| Timestamp | participant | level | gold | participant | level | gold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 | 6000 | 2 | 76 | 4200 |
| 2 | 1 | 150 | 5000 | 2 | 120 | 3700 |

I am trying to change the Dataframe so that all rows from columns named the same is moved below each other, while keeping the column named timestamp:

| Timestamp | participant | level | gold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 | 6000 |
| 2 | 1 | 150 | 5000 |
| 1 | 2 | 76 | 4200 |
| 2 | 2 | 120 | 3700 |

To be clear, the example above is a small sample, the actual Dataframe has a lot of columnes named the same, and a lot more rows. Hence, the solution needs to take that in to account.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Idea is deduplicated duplicated columns names by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter and then reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = df.set_index('Timestamp')
s = df.columns.to_series()

df.columns = [df.columns, s.groupby(s).cumcount()]

df = df.stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
```

If columns names are not duplicated and added `.` with number:

```
print (df)
   Timestamp  participant  level  gold  participant.1  level.1  gold.1
0          1            1    100  6000              2       76    4200
1          2            1    150  5000              2      120    3700

df = df.set_index('Timestamp')

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df.columns.str.split('.', expand=True)
                                        .to_frame().fillna('0'))

df = df.stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
print (df)
0  Timestamp  gold  level  participant
0          1  6000    100            1
1          1  4200     76            2
2          2  5000    150            1
3          2  3700    120            2
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
df1=pd.concat([df.iloc[:,0],df.loc[:,df.columns.duplicates()]],axis=1)
df2=df.loc[:,~df.columns.duplicates()]
df=pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
```

Comment: Many thanks! This migth work, but the challange is that there are multiple columnes and rows, so the solution needs to be more generic.

Comment: changed the solution for something better